# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, pipeline, tf.keras

I want to create a `sklearn` pipeline that consists of two steps:

1. Custom transformer function
2. Keras classification model

This is my data set (of course, I'm providing a reduced subset to show the data format):

**x_train**

```
array([[[0.45977011, 0.16666667, 0.18373494, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.71317829, 0.7246617 ],
        [0.6091954 , 0.25      , 0.28313253, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.66666667, 0.73101353],
        [0.25287356, 0.75      , 0.34337349, ..., 0.16666667,
         0.62790698, 0.62137531],
        ...,
        [0.6091954 , 0.58333333, 0.20481928, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.62015504, 0.65009666],
        [0.41954023, 0.91666667, 0.30722892, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.71317829, 0.76719138],
        [0.31609195, 0.41666667, 0.46987952, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.5503876 , 0.71306269]],

       [[0.6091954 , 0.25      , 0.28313253, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.66666667, 0.73101353],
        [0.25287356, 0.75      , 0.34337349, ..., 0.16666667,
         0.62790698, 0.62137531],
        [0.54022989, 0.5       , 0.34337349, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.57364341, 0.66238608],
        ...,
        [0.41954023, 0.91666667, 0.30722892, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.71317829, 0.76719138],
        [0.31609195, 0.41666667, 0.46987952, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.5503876 , 0.71306269],
        [0.44252874, 0.75      , 0.48192771, ..., 0.41666667,
         0.62015504, 0.65023474]],

       [[0.25287356, 0.75      , 0.34337349, ..., 0.16666667,
         0.62790698, 0.62137531],
        [0.54022989, 0.5       , 0.34337349, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.57364341, 0.66238608],
        [0.3908046 , 0.33333333, 0.34939759, ..., 0.41666667,
         0.58914729, 0.70450152],
        ...,
        [0.31609195, 0.41666667, 0.46987952, ..., 0.33333333,
         0.5503876 , 0.71306269],
        [0.44252874, 0.75      , 0.48192771, ..., 0.41666667,
         0.62015504, 0.65023474],
        [0.60344828, 0.41666667, 0.46686747, ..., 0.25      ,
         0.66666667, 0.61391881]]]
```

**y_train**

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

And this is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.utils import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Custom transformer
class Transformer():

    def transform(self, x):
        x_img = np.apply_along_axis(self.rec_plot, 1, x).astype('float16')
        return x_img
    
    def rec_plot(s, eps=0.10, steps=10):
        d = pdist(s[:,None])
        d = np.floor(d/eps)
        d[d>steps] = steps
        Z = squareform(d)
        return Z
    
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return x

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 17)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    #sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model.summary())
    
    return model

transformer = Transformer()
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

blackbox_model = Pipeline([('transform', transformer),('clf',clf)])
blackbox_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

When I run this code on my dataset, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'

It seems to be related to the data format (therefore, I shared my data format above). But I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Transformer().fit()` should return `self`.

Because your `Transformer` object is stateless, it might be easier to use `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer`. You can instantiate that class with your transform function. Something like the following (untested):

```
import sklearn.preprocessing

def _rec_plot(s, eps=0.10, steps=10):
    d = pdist(s[:,None])
    d = np.floor(d/eps)
    d[d>steps] = steps
    Z = squareform(d)
    return Z

def fun(x, y=None):
    return np.apply_along_axis(_rec_plot, 1, x).astype('float16')

transformer = sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(func=fun)
```

I also suggest not using the syntax `from module import *` because that can pollute your namespace. When I first read your question, I wondered if the problem was clashing function names because of all of the unnecessary imports.

Comment: Thanks. Now get another error `TypeError: 'Transformer' object is not subscriptable`. Do you know how to make my example working?

Comment: Ok, I see. Now the error is `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`. Indeed `x_train` is a 3-dimensional array. Does it mean that I should add the transfromation from 2D to 3D as another step in `Pipeline`?

Comment: It seems that sklearn works with 2D arrays, not 3D. So you can reshape your data to be 2D before the `Transformer()`, then reshape to be 3D before you pass it to the Keras classifier. I assume the Keras classifier can handle 3D arrays.

Comment: yes, Keras works fine with 3D. The problem is with the Pipeline of transformations. I posted my new question here in case you could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330277/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-id